# Add Score just Once inGame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have Platform in my Game and by the platform , Player take score.
but the problem is that if player dont move the character and just stay in one platform , take score.
now i want to do something for this to give score for each platform just once.
i made a boolian but it works for all platform not each platform that instantiate because it works with tags
here is my script :

```
public float JumpPower;
public AudioSource PlatformSFX;
private bool UsedScore = false;
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.relativeVelocity.y <= 0f)
    {
        Rigidbody2D rb = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, JumpPower);
        }
        if (this.gameObject.CompareTag("ScoreZone") && UsedScore)
        {
            UsedScore = true;
            ScoreSystem.ScoreSystem.ScoreValue += 165;
            PlatformSFX.Play();
        }
        if (this.gameObject.CompareTag("ScoreZone") && !UsedScore)
        {
           
            PlatformSFX.Play();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question, as it's not apparent what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **!UsedScore** in condition.

```
if (this.gameObject.CompareTag("ScoreZone") && !UsedScore)
        {
            UsedScore = true;
            ScoreSystem.ScoreSystem.ScoreValue += 165;
            PlatformSFX.Play();
        }
```

And **UsedScore** in below

```
if (this.gameObject.CompareTag("ScoreZone") && UsedScore)
        {
           
            PlatformSFX.Play();
        }
```